# How respond to prompts in bash

Tags: bash, openssl

I need to generate a lot of private keys and self signed certs so I'd like to make a bash script to do it for me. The problem I've run into is that when you self sign a cert it asks the same questions as if you were generating a signing request.

Namely:

```
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:  
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]: 
Locality Name (eg, city) []: 
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]: 
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []: 
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []: 
Email Address []: 

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
An optional company name []:
```

I've tried several things that I've seen around the site but none of them seem to work. This is probably because I'm very new to bash.

My script currently looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 2048

openssl req -new -key privkey.pem -out cert.csr
```

I've tried using a pipe where echo the things I'd like to enter but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: read the manual page for [openssl req](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html); specifically the section regarding the configuration file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the examples provided at:

```
http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html#EXAMPLES
```

Or do everything in the command line:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -x509\ 
 -subj "/C=US/ST=Denial /L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com" \
 -keyout www.example.com.key  -out www.example.com.cert
```